# Probability of picking 2 balls with the same colour

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A bag contains three red balls, three black balls, and three blue balls. You pick two balls at random (without replacement). Given that you pick two balls with the same colour, what is the probability that they are blue?

I let A be the event 'you pick 2 balls of the same colour' and
I let B be the event 'you pick to blue balls'

To work out P(B|A), first I tried to find the P(A), which I believe is 3/9*1/2 however, I'm unsure what to do after.

Comment: Well, symmetry makes the answer pretty clear, no?

Comment: @lulu Symmetry makes me believe the answer is 1/3, but I would like to know how to get to that answer

Comment: Symmetry is a proof, of course.  The only way to get two of the same color is to get two reds, two blues, or two blacks and it is clear that these are equiprobable.  Otherwise, just compute the probability of getting two reds (or two blues, etc.).

Comment: Note:  to get the probability of drawing two of the same color, note that the first ball can have any color and that, then, there is a $\frac 28=\frac 14$ chance that the second will have the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{\frac{3}{9}\times \frac{2}{8}}{3\times\frac{3}{9}\times\frac{2}{8}}$$

$P(A)$ is the probability of two balls are same color

$P(B)$ is the probability of two balls are blue